# How to create task manager solution?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I download task manager from [this site](https://dnntaskmanager.codeplex.com/), after the module has been downloaded I load installtion zip file as module to the DNN.

How can I create solution in visual studio from this module(task manager solution)?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by following the tutorial/directions linked on that codeplex page

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/module-development#_Beginning_Module_Development_Video_Series__6

You can also install the SOURCE version of the module http://dnntaskmanager.codeplex.com/releases/view/73062

then you will have the VS files you need. One thing you will need to do is recreate the .DNN file though as DNN makes that go away (you can copy it from the ZIP file)

Comment: Chris, thanks I watched videos realy really helped me to understand DNN!!!
 But my question is how can I open Task Manager in Visual Studio? After I create a module from a TaskManager_00.00.01_Install.zip in DNN  the folder named  TaskManager has been created in this pass "C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\".
In TaskManager folder I have few files (Edit.ascx,Settings.ascx,View.ascx) but I dont see file with extension .sln  so my question how can I open the project (TaskManager) in Visual Studio?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should install the SOURCE version not the INSTALL version